# Why is the root package in source code called "com"?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, package

In most source codes, the root package/folder is named "com". Why is that so? It it just convention or does it stand for something?

Answer (score 51):

The [convention](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) is that a programmer in a given organization will start package names with their organization's domain name, as a unique identifier -- in reverse order.  This prevents namespace clashes between code from different organizations (within the organization you're on your own).

So if I work for a company called Supercompany, and their domain is supercompany.com, all of my package names will start with `com.supercompany`.  And since a lot of code is written for companies, a lot of packages start with com.  However, there are plenty of packages that start with "net" or "org" or other such top-level domains.  Myself, I work for a university, so my package names generally start with "edu".

The brief answer, then, is that most package names start with "com" because most domain names end with "com".

Answer (score 7):

Its not necessary that it always start with **.com**.

### What is it exactly?

Its actually package naming convension.

### How to decide root package name?

Generally we android developer having practice to decide package name based on the domain name of a particular company.

For example:

> 1. Domain name: **sun.com** => Root package name something like : **com.sun**
> 2. Domain name: **technotalkative.com** => Root package name something like: **com.technotalkative.android**
> 3. Domain name: **sun.org** => Root package name something like: **org.sun.androidapp**

For more information, check: [**What should be the package name of android app?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075162/what-should-be-the-package-name-of-android-app/8075247#8075247)

Answer (score 2):

Because it's sun.*com* and the vast majority of packages come from a company. For apache.org packages, the root is *org*, and so on. It's just a reverse (canonical) domain name namespace.