# Package Name for Personal Android App

Tags: java, android, package

If i want to create an Android application and publish it on the market, can I use com.wordpress.MyName.appName as my package name ?

What's usually the package name for publishing personal applications in the android market ?

Comment: com.yourcompanyname.yourprojectname would be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package name can be literally anything and everything. But when you publish an app on the market place, you need to make sure that your package name is unique.

So, if already someone is using the name of the package in an already published app, you can't use it.

The reason is that if the package name is same for two apps then the phone OS needs to uninstall the previous app before installing the new one as two apps with the same package name cant co-exist in a phone.

So, it is advisable to make your unique package name and use it while publishing the apps on the marketplace.

I feel that this would be the best way to do it.

**[com/edu/org/...].[organizationName].[projectName + version/date]**

Answer (score 0):

You can use any Package Name you like, and which fits your organisation!
The Main Package just has to be unique on Android Market (the full package name, you can for example publish com.wordpress.alt if com.wordpress is already published on the market)

Answer (score 0):

You should perhaps create your own unique package name as this associates it with your software. "com.wordpress" will be used by the Wordpress software. Think of it like a reverse internet address.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to use the same approach as for Java in general. For example, base it on your email address (as suggested here: http://c2.com/ppr/wiki/JavaIdioms/JavaPackageNames.html)

Answer (score 0):

Read this two pages about Package name

[Android package name](http://blog.javia.org/android-package-name/) and [What should be the package name of android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075162/what-should-be-the-package-name-of-android-app)

*Only need to take care that the name you have, is not already there in market.*