# Error publishing app to the Google Play.

Tags: android, google-play, xamarin, publish

I have a problem while uploading .apk file. When I try to upload .apk file, I always get the same error:

[image]

Its says that I need to name the app file, something like this: **com.example.myapp**.

The .apk names that I tried (examples): **com.rvislt.prosld**.apk, **com.rvislt.prosld2014**.apk and I always got the above error.

I tried to use the different browsers, shutdown all background application and I always got the same error.

It makes me crazy!

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the error saying in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply renaming the APK file name, try to change your package name of your application.

Like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rvislt.prosld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1" >
```

Renaming the APK file to `com.rvislt.prosld.apk` does not make any sense and it wont work for you.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I think that was the problem. I will try to upload the .apk tomorrow, because now I have reached my daily upload limit. :(

Answer (score 2):

Try to change `Package Name` into your `manifest.xml` file with `com.rvislt.prosld` and built again and for the naming conversation go to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Its not necessary that it always start with `.com`.

Generally we android developer having practice to decide package name based on the domain name of a particular company.

For example:

```
 1. Domain name: sun.com => Root package name something like : com.sun
 2. Domain name: technotalkative.com => Root package name something like: com.technotalkative.android
 3. Domain name: sun.org => Root package name something like: org.sun.androidapp
```

And for more information, [What should be the package name of android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075162/what-should-be-the-package-name-of-android-app/8075247#8075247)

Comment: Thanks for advice. I think that was the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

After having refactored your project to use new package name try to use a find-replace in your project and replace `com.youroldpackage.app` with `com.yournewpackage.app` with eclipse.

There are several places where your app page name is used: Manifest etc. java packages etc. make sure that everywhere is used your new package now.

BTW: a good practice for package naming is to use a domain that you own in it, that way you can be almost sure that nobody else uses the same package name, which is a problem, because you cannot upload apps with a package name that is already in use. so for example if you have the domain "mynewpackage.com" then your app packagename should be something like `com.mynewpackage.mynewapp`