# Does my Android application name have to be com.myAppName

Tags: c#, android

I'm new to Android development and I am working in Visual Studio 2015, using C#.
I'm up to the point where I need to digitally sign my application before testing it at the appStore, and I'm seeing a lot of app names with "com." some name.
Do I need to rename my app and add the com.?

I searched here and Google and could not find the correct answer.  If so then why the com.?

Comment: sort of same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075162/what-should-be-the-package-name-of-android-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you don't need to rename your app.**

The name(com.****) you are talking about is the package name of your app. Infact, name of the app has nothing to do with the package name of your app.

**Package name** : This is an unique name, throughout the play store, for your app.

`I'm seeing a lot of app names with "com." some name.`

The reason for this is that popular app developers, rename their APKs with the package name and version, to help maintain the app better within the company and identify the app easily with the APK name. The reason they usually start with "com." is that (as I mentioned before if you want to place your app in play store, package name has to be unique) the domain names are obviously unique. So they give the package name to be their domain name in reverse followed by nickname of the app and then version number. For example `com.facebook.katana_v90.0.0.20.70-36474238_Android-5.0.apk`

**App name** : This is the name that appears under your app icon after it has been installed. It can be "anything" (may not allow some special characters and have a size limit).

Comment: Thank you so much, that explanation helped a lot. Especially the domain name in reverse.  Being a .Net developer all these years, I never had to deal with this.  
Android has proved to be interesting and challenging.
So my app will be com.[my company name].[my app name],[my app name] since it names it twice in VS.  My company name is also my domain name.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a domain name, it does not matter if .com, co.uk or whatever.

Comment: So if the name of my app is MyApp then its namespace is Myapp, then the name will be MyApp.MyApp

Comment: No, you need a domain name, like google.com or bbc.co.uk