# Package name in Android

Tags: android, package

Is it mandatory to start the package name with com. ? I have a different package name like xxxx.yyyy.com.xxxx . Will google play accept it ? Is there any harm in uploading the app with such type of package name .

Thank you in Advance for help.

Comment: check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075162/what-should-be-the-package-name-of-android-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Package Name convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273892/android-package-name-convention)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not mandatory.

Even standard Android components use package names like `android.foo.bar`. Or Java components like `java.util.foo`.

Comment: my package is like  myapp.myappinc.com.myapp