# How to create an app in flutter using the namespace "com.example"?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a flutter app using vscode and now I am trying to upload the bundle to the Google Play store but I am getting an error:

```
You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted.
```

I don't have a domain name so how can I do this without changing the namespace in the app/build.gradle file or do I need to have a domain?

UPDATE:
I ran the "rename" command as was suggested in the answer but now when I run the app I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.kane.dealdiligence' in C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\android\app\google-services.json
```

Can I manually edit the .json file or do I need to recreate it in firebase?
Thanks

Comment: Change package name you can check this answer [explain how to change package name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51550358/11217742)

Comment: also check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59353204/11217742

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have a **package ID** if you want to publish on Google Play. This doesn't necessarily mean you have to have a real domain (i.e. for a website); it can be **fictive**, but should be **unique**. So just use a domain that represents you or your company. Please consider the aspect that the domain is **reverse**.

For example, you could use `"com.losttexan.myapp"`

There is a pretty handy package/CLI tool called [rename](https://pub.dev/packages/rename).
You can use it to modify both your package ID and your app name.

Example use (from the [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/rename)):

```
rename setBundleId --targets android --value "com.example.bundleId"
```

Also, make sure to set the namespace in the `app/build.gradle` file appropriately:

```
android {
    namespace "com.example.bundleId"
    ...
}
```