# Package naming conventions

Tags: android

We usually have this naming convention - `com.something.something` in Android.
Is it valid if we do not use the `com.` part and just keep it like `something.something` (provided that `something.something` is unique)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4620116/6441416

I don't think it would be valid but anyway.
Look through his answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Android follows the naming convention as Java, I think it doesn't make any difference if it is a unique application id..

As per Android Developers

**If you have a company domain www.example.com**

Than you should use:

com.example.region.projectname

**If you own a domain name like example.co.uk than it should be:**

uk.co.example.region.projectname

But though **many application doesn't have any prefix of domain and also they are running on Play Store** for example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to naming an apk is starting with com.somthing.But not mandatory for google play store.This format comes to make an app id is unique.So you can give your app id anything you want to.